# Schedule and MANUALLY run .pyw script in Task Scheduler on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, taskscheduler

I would like to schedule a .pyw script in Task Scheduler on Windows. When I double click on the file, everything works properly, the program does what it should do. I successfully create a task in Task Scheduler: -'Run with highest privileges' checked -Configure for Windows 10 -'At system startup' trigger -Action: 'Start a program' and I provide the full path to the .pyw script -I have also unchecked 'Start the task only if the computer is on AC power'

..and when I do right click --> Run, I get a standard question: "How do you want to open this file" etc. Now, status of the task is 'Running', but nothing happens, and I cannot find my program running in Task Manager. Any advice?

Comment: Task Scheduler does not reliably look up file associations when creating a task. Avoid this can of worms by explicitly running the fully-qualified path of "pythonw.exe" and configuring the fully-qualified path of the script as a command-line argument. I stress that both paths must be fully qualified. If the script directory contains spaces, quote it with double-quote characters.

Comment: Also, the script should make no assumption about the working directory. If it needs private resource files, they should be referenced relative to the script directory, not the working directory.